# Hosting Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

I am running an app on localhost:3000, and now I am looking to host it using my home network.
I am running on windows machine, I have looked at number of guides but none seem to be complete enough.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you mean that you will be using your computer's IP address as public IP... (People on other machines will be able to access your app using your machine's IP)

Answer (score 0):

when you run your app in localhost:3000, you app in that moment is in online , in your private network... if you wanna check your app from outside pc.

you will need  this point.

```
1- check the principal adress pc,  the ip
2- you computer, shut down your firewall,,  some times block you app.
3- in your second computer, connect in the same wifi, and  put adress  in a 
 browser and port, and you will  saw you app online
```

EXAMPLE NO REAL

change **ww.example.com**  by    **1.63.21.0:3000**

to keep you app, all the time running, when you app is finished, you will need this comand.

**`forever start app.js`**

that means, all the time of you computer is turn on, you app will start, to give a service, in this case your app

reference
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

if you really wanna build a server, and put your pc in the internet world, you will need configurate you modem and buy some adress..  like a host in internet, a domain, hope help you with this message

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a service like Heroku instead of your home network, it has way better uptime, and you only have to worry about the code in your app instead of the networking and system architecture.